# Cloned Virtual Machine, Java services will not start

Tags: java, windows-services, virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, yajsw

In our software environment we have a number of VMs running Windows Server 2008 R2. On these servers we have Java 1.6 and use YAJSW for a couple of services. As part of our upgrade procedure we want to create clones on the virtual environments and test our upgrades before deploying to production.

Now for the issue.... The windows services will not start on the cloned VMs.

An example of a command that is run when a service is started is:

> F:\app\configservice>"D:/Java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/java.exe" "-classpath" "D:\yajsw-10.8\wrapper.jar" "-Xrs" "-Dwrapper.service=true" "-Dwrapper.working.dir=f:\app\configservice" "-Dwrapper.java.command=D:/Java/jdk1.6.0_27/bin/configservice.exe" "-Dwrapper.config=F:\app\configservice\lib\wrapper.conf" "-Dwrapper.additional.1x=-Xrs" "org.rzo.yajsw.boot.WrapperServiceBooter"

When run manually from the command line it produces this output.

> INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|init
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|Win service: before service init
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|set state IDLE->STARTING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|starting Process
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|error in >StartServiceCtrlDispatcher
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|1063:The service process could not connect to the service controller.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service ConfigService|13-02-11 14:37:49|Win service: terminated correctly

Googling the error has led me to believe there may be something wrong with the JVM, but that really does not make sense as it is a clone of a VM where the JVM is perfectly happy. Some colleagues have suggested the group rights policies, but it seems to be the same on both machines.

Comment: Perhaps an IP address is configured somewhare

Comment: It is hard to tell from what info you have provided, but I would suggest you scan the configuration files and startup scripts for something machine-specific, like an IP Address, Hostname, or Windows Computer or User Account.

Comment: I forgot to mention... The clones do receive new IPs and hostnames. I am not sure if that can have an adverse effect on the JVM

Comment: I can actually run the service as a Java application from the command prompt, so the JVM is not to blame here. Funny enough when I start the service I can see it quickly using 7mb RAM and then just sit and do nothing, not even log. From the command prompt it goes almost immediately to 48mb and works happily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using psexec I created a Local System level command prompt and starting checking the environment variables. I found that the local user's temp directory mapped to a non existing drive. Further digging revealed that Y: was mapped as E: on the cloned VM. Not sure how that happened, but the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you run cloned VM in the same network as original one, make sure it has different MAC and IP.